# Neo4j/Cypher : do not allow a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, project-planning

I am creating a PERT tool, and adapting this [tutorial](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/8e1d6ff9-f7fa-4c99-9c5d-ecb94ba46d81) to my case.

What I want to do is forbidding the creation of relationships, and the creation of properties:

1. The START node (which is an **:EndPoint**, not an **:Activity**) should not have predecessors, only successors
2. The FINISH node (which is an **:EndPoint**, not an **:Activity**) should not have successors, only predecessors
3. No CYCLE allowed

   - Each **:Activity** directly preceding by START cannot have other activities as predecessors
   - Each **:Activity** (in+)directly predecessor of a activities cannot have these activities as predecessors.

I have not found a way to block these relationships creations. The constraints do not seem to be what I want to do, the UNIQUENESS is not at all what I am looking for.

I tried to take the problem in an other way :

1. Authorise only successors property for the START:EndPoint
2. Authorise only predecessors property for the FINISH:EndPoint

but for the 3rd point, I have no idea, and the "reverse-thinking" could be a solution, but I did not find how to apply it.

If you have any idea, even not working, but giving a new vision, I would really appreciate.

Comment: "forbidding the creation of relationships, and the creation of properties" - I understand the relationships part, but what properties would you like to forbid? "Authorise only successors property for the START:EndPoint" - are you sure this is a property and not a relationship?

Comment: Also, if both the start and the finish nodes are EndPoints, how do you tell the difference between them?

Comment: ☼ Thank you Gabor for your questions.

It's a web-based tool, and when the user creates a project, the two endpoints are created at the same time.

The START:EndPoint as the properties {position:"Start", ES:0, EF:0, LS:0, LF:0, successors:[]}
The FINISH:EndPoint as the properties {position:"Finish", ES:0, EF:0, LS:0, LF:0, predecessors:[]}

In the arrays, the activities.names connected to these endpoints are stored for an HTML purpose, but I do not read the data inside the arrays for my queries.

ES = Earliest Start
EF = Earliest Finish
LS = Latest Start
LF = Latest Finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what is custom here I'm going to give an opinion. The reason being that you're actually not talking about restrictions at the level of the database (aka **schema**) but restrictions at the level of your problem (aka **business rules**).

There are lots of ways to implement business logic the main (and probably the best) one being ... **in your application logic**.

A Neo4j specific one would be to use **user defined procedures**. Not unlike the use of **stored procedures and triggers** that you might use to solve similar problems in an RDBMS such as Oracle.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: ☼ Thank you Tom for your time and your opinion ! It was the new vision I needed ! I will definitely work on it. Thank you again,

Regards, 
Suraja

Answer (score 1):

You correctly concluded that using constraints is not the right approach here. While they are [proposed to the openCypher language](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/website/ocim2/slides/10.00+Constraints+syntax.pdf), this is an ongoing process and structural constraints are not supported by current implementations.

I agree with Tom Geudens' answer: you should prevent the creation of relationships that would violate your constraints in the application logic.